# MongoDB collection error undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am facing an issue while inserting data into collection.it gives an error of **cannot read property of collection undefined.** provide a solution of it i try my best.
here is my code.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var querystring = require('querystring');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url ="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/college";

var port = 4000;
http.createServer((req,res) => {

    if(req.url==="/form")
    {
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text:html"});
        fs.createReadStream("./public/form.html" , "UTF-8").pipe(res);
    }
    if(req.method==="POST")
    {
        var data = " ";
        req.on("data", function(chunk) 
        {
            data += chunk;
        });
        req.on("end" , function(chunk){

             MongoClient.connect(url , function(err,db){
                 if(err) throw err;
                 var q = querystring.parse(data).
                 db.collection('res').insertOne(q,function(err,res){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log("data is insert");
                    db.close();
                 });

             })
        });
    }
}).listen(port);
console.log(port);
```

[here is erro i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dotQV.png)

Comment: Is your MongoClient connected well ? Can you give us the full stack of your error ?

Comment: Like it say in your error, it canno't find collection function of undefined. So your db Object is undefined, you have probably an error when you try to connect to mongo

Comment: i also post my question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code, check in debug mode what's happen when you do
    MongoClient.connect({...})

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest your to go this way.

1- Don't use database name in when `creating mongodburl` i-e

replace

```js
var url ="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/college";
```

with

```js
var url ="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
```

And now when you try to connect with `mongodb` server you'll get `mongodb constructor` in the callback function so you'll have to add one extra line of code. Something like below

```js
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, dbC) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var db = dbC.db("college");
    var q = querystring.parse(data).
        db.collection('res').insertOne(q, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("data is insert");
            db.close();
        });

})
```

This way you'll get `res` collection defined for the `database` `college` (I am assuming you've already defined that collection in your database with some query like `db.createCollection('res')`)  and then it should work

Thanks